# guzzle returns error 404 while postman 200

Tags: php, guzzle

I've been trying to post using guzzle but i keep getting the following error : `Client error: 404` in console.

The function looks like this:

```
public function testApi_postRule()
{
    $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://10.0.0.0/rule']);
    $response = $client->post('placement=guzzle_unique_placement&device=desktop&active=1');
}
```

So I tried to use postman to see if the problem is in the code so in postman I set the url : `http://10.0.0.0/rule` and passed the same params with same values and I got the lovely `200` response..

Any idea what am i doing wrong in guzzle?

Comment: Looks like guzzle's post has [this signature](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#query-string-parameters); so,  `$client->post( 'http://.../rule', [ 'query' => 'placement=.....active=1'] )`.  (Also, 10.0.0.0 would be a network address, not typically a host address..)

Comment: didn't work for me...error 400

Comment: Try pre-pending a `/` onto your POST route. e.g. `$client->post('/placement=...`